# How to access <sql:query> result set of jsp inside <script>

Tags: javascript, sql, jsp, jstl, fullcalendar-6

I am trying to use FullCalendar library to design an interactive calendar where user can click on a date to see the corresponding course schedule/ event. For this I need to populate the events in this calendar with my database table data. This needs calendar rendering inside JavaScript. I am facing trouble in accessing database result sets, that I retrieved in JSP, inside JavaScript.

Although my sql table (course) is having multiple columns, only things I need for calendar are course name and date.
I have used `<sql:query>` in the jsp code for data retrieval from the mysql table. The result is in `var="schedule"`. Next, I have used `<c:forEach>` to iterate through the result sets and store them in a `var="jsonData"`. I tried printing `${jsonData}` in JSP within a `<h2>` tag and data retrieved in json format is shown. However, when I am trying to access the same inside `<script>` tag, it is not working as

```
console.log(${jsonData})
```

or even

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(${jsonData}))
```

shows

```
[Object Object][Object Object][Object Object]...
```

for all the records.

**EDIT**

Following is my code :

```
<body>
<div class="container">     
        <div class="row justify-content-around">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div id="about-card">
                            <div class="card bg-light text-dark">
                                <div class="card-header text-center">           
                                    <h2 class="mt-3">Monthly Schedule</h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div id='calendar0' class="bg-light text-dark"></div>
                                    <!-- Custom year navigation buttons -->
                                    <div id='year-navigation'>
                                        <button id='prev-year-button'>Previous Year</button>
                                        <button id='next-year-button'>Next Year</button>
                                    </div>  
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="about-card">
                    <div class="card bg-light text-dark">
                        <div class="card-header text-center">           
                            <h2 class="mt-3">Schedule details</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div id='schedule'>
                                <p style="color:#406e8e;">Please click on a date to see schedule</p>
                            </div> <!-- This div will hold the schedule information -->     
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>                                                                                              
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Data retrieval -->
    <sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDb?useSSL=false" user="root" password="dummypswd"/>

    <sql:query dataSource = "${snapshot}" var="schedule">
        select session_name,date from course;       
    </sql:query>

<!-- converting results to JSON format -->
<c:set var="jsonData" value="[]"/>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${schedule.rows}">          
    <c:set var="session_name" value="${row.session_name}"/>
    <c:set var="date" value="${row.date}"/>
    
    <c:set var="jsonObject" value='{"session_name":"${session_name }","date":"${date}"}'/>
    <c:set var="jsonData" value='${jsonData} + ${jsonObject}'/>
    <c:if test="${!status.last}">,</c:if>
    
</c:forEach>
<c:set var="theData" value="${jsonData}"/>

<!-- Scripts -->
<h2>Here json data is ${jsonData}</h2> <!--This is printing real fetched data on jsp page-->
<script>
        //With all these variables, I am just trying to check how can i get correct jsonData inside script
        var jData = ${jsonData};
        var ev = JSON.stringify(jData);
        var d = ${theData};

        console.log("The data ",d); //But none of these printing fetched data
        console.log("JSON ev  ",ev);
        console.log("JSONdata  ",jData);
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                 var events = [
                // sample data
                { title: 'Course 1', start: '2023-09-05T11:00:00' },
                { title: 'Course 2', start: '2023-09-15' },
                { title: 'Course 3', start: '2023-09-15' },
                { title: 'Basic Maths Assignment due', start: '2023-09-23', url: 'index.jsp'},
                { title: 'Hazard Management Assignment due', start: '2023-09-15', url: 'index.jsp'}
                // Add more event data here from database-- TODO
                //This is where I need my fetched data in JSON format. Please help.
            ]; 
            console.log(events);
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar0');
            var scheduleEl = document.getElementById('schedule');
            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                //left: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear today',
                //center: 'title',
                //right: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay',
                initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                events: events,
                dateClick: function(info) {
                    // Handle date click event here
                    // To load and display course information for the clicked date
                    //alert('Clicked on: ' + info.dateStr);
                    // To load and display course information for the clicked date
                    var clickedDate = info.dateStr;

                    // Simulate loading schedule data 
                    var scheduleData = [
                        { time: '10:00 AM - 12:00 PM', event: 'Course 1 Details' },
                        { time: '2:00 PM - 4:00 PM', event: 'Course 2 Details' }
                    ];

                    // Generate HTML for the schedule
                    var scheduleHTML = '<h4>Schedule for ' + clickedDate + '</h4>';
                    scheduleHTML += '<ul>';
                    scheduleData.forEach(function(item) {
                        scheduleHTML += '<li><b>' + item.time + '</b>: ' + item.event + '</li>';
                    });
                    scheduleHTML += '</ul>';

                    // Update the schedule container with the generated HTML
                    scheduleEl.innerHTML = scheduleHTML;
                }
            });
        
            calendar.render();
         // Custom year navigation buttons
            var currentYear = moment().year(); // Get the current year
            // Function to update the calendar to the previous year
            function goToPreviousYear() {
                currentYear--;
                calendar.gotoDate(currentYear + '-01-01'); // Navigate to the previous year
            }

            // Function to update the calendar to the next year
            function goToNextYear() {
                currentYear++;
                calendar.gotoDate(currentYear + '-01-01'); // Navigate to the next year
            }

            // Attach event listeners to the custom year navigation buttons
            document.getElementById('prev-year-button').addEventListener('click', goToPreviousYear);
            document.getElementById('next-year-button').addEventListener('click', goToNextYear);
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

Edit 2:

I have tried JSON.parse() . Following are the screenshots
[image: code snippet]

Following is the error displayed in console
[image: error]

If I try `console.log("JSON ev ",jData)` @line 140, I get object object as follows
[image: error2]

Answer (score 0):

The value of JSON is already stringified . You don't need to do it twice.

The following code is wrong

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(${jsonData}))
```

However, `${jsonData}` returns a string value. You need to parse it to get JSON object with [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please see my code that I have added later. I have tried parsing also earlier, but that is also printing [Object Object]

Comment: It is not json object, you should post a error stacktrace when you tried to parse it with JSON.parse().

Comment: after using var jData = JSON.parse(${jsonData}); console.log(jData); i get error : Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: What is a unexpected token? I asked you to include a stacktrace of error.

Comment: please check, I have included the screenshots of error

Comment: The line JSON.parse(jData) is causing this error because if I print something else in that block, that error is gone. So, it is sure that jData or ${jsonData} return a String. But how do I use it inside the script to access database data?

Comment: The script is executed in the browser, but jsonData is printed on server. Since you didn't serialize any object on the server then it's impossible to parse a string returned by ${jsonData}. You need to debug your code to get why it's not valid.